# and the web.config transformation just won't work.... won't work grrrrr

Tags: asp.net, web-config-transform

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have this web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>      
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="domain\allow" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>      
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now I have gone to solution -> Configuration Manager and added a new configuration called "Production"

Now I came and right click on my web.config and clicked "Add Config Transforms"

Now I can see a file called web.Production.config

I go and add this to my file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FooDB" connectionString="Data Source=FooServer;Initial Catalog=FooDB;Integrated Security=True;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now when I build and publish my project I see an error message

```
Web.Production.config(17,4): Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'
```

Comment: Are you setting the publish profile to `Production` during the publishing?

Comment: Maybe because the `connectionStrings` element does not exist in your base `Web.config`. You could try adding an empty node for it. Mine has a value I want for local debugging and I use **replace** transform instead of **add**.

Comment: Yes. I double checked and the profile does use 'Production' as build configuration. However I did notice an error in the output `\Web.Production.config(3,4): Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `connectionStrings` to the main web.config. The only things that should appear in your production config are the transformations.

Comment: My point is that there is no connectionString to transform so there's no need for it to be there. So either move it to web.config or remove it entirely.

Comment: I'm just assuming that he doesn't want the connectionString to be present during debugging, since he's going through the trouble of adding it with a publish profile.

Comment: I do need the the connection string during development. that is why I in configuration manager I have a profile called Development.

Comment: When I say _debugging_ I'm referring to you building locally and running the application from localhost, which means you wouldn't be publishing. Like I said earlier, the Web.config file should have your _local_ settings and the publish profiles should be how you want the deployed application to be configured on your various environments (Production, Test, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to use publish profiles. Here's what worked for me:

Call your additional Web.config files `Web.Debug.config` (Test) and `Web.Release.config` (Production) then during publishing you associate `Debug` configuration to the **Test** publish profile and `Release` configuration to the **Production** publish profile.

EDIT:

Try changing the `xdt:Transform` to `Insert` and removing the `xdt:Locator` attribute.